# Is it possible to take c# like textchange event in java

Tags: jsp, servlets

In c# have TextChanged event:

```
protected void txtbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Is any equivalent in java?

Comment: Are you using Swing or something?

Comment: No  i am not using Swings jsp,servlet only